# cblas linking: undefined reference to `cblas_dgemv'

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cblas

I am trying to use cblas library to use BLAS. I call cblas function from a custom C function and then link this file to my C++ file. But I get this error

```
Cfile.o: In function `mm_blas':
Cfile.c:(.text+0xbf): undefined reference to `cblas_dgemv'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My **Cfile.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cblas.h>

void f(double dd[])
{
    int i;
      for (i=0; i<2; ++i)  printf("%5.1f\n", dd[i]);
    printf("\n This is a C code\n");
}

    double m[] = {
  3, 1, 3,
  1, 5, 9,
  2, 6, 5
};

double x[] = {
  -1, -1, 1
};

double y[] = {
  0, 0, 0
};

void mm_blas(double m1[], double m2[], double m3[], int m_size){
  cblas_dgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, 3, 3, 1.0, m, 3, x, 1, 0.0, y, 1);
}
```

**And main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

extern "C" {
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cblas.h>

    void f(double []);
    void mm_blas(double [], double [], double [], int);
}

void func(void)
{
    std::cout<<"\n being used within C++ code\n";
}

int main(void)
{
    double dd [] = {1,2,3};
    f(dd);
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile the code with command

```
gcc -c -lblas Cfile.c -o Cfile.o  && g++ -std=c++11 -lblas -o  myfoobar Cfile.o main.cpp && ./myfoobar
```

I am on Linux, gcc 4.8. How to solve this problem.

Comment: Is libblas installed and reachable?

Comment: @LPs If not there would have been a different error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
gcc -c Cfile.c -o Cfile.o  && g++ -std=c++11 -o  myfoobar Cfile.o main.cpp -lblas && ./myfoobar
```

a) There is no point in passing linkage options (`-lblas`) to `gcc -c ...`
because `-c` means *don't link*.

b) In the linkage sequence, by default, files that require symbol definitions must occur before
the ones that provide the definitions. So object files before the libraries that
they refer to, else the libraries are ignored and the references are unresolved.